# AJAX 403 forbidden when making ajax request

Tags: ajax, general-network-error

The website initiates ajax request but always get return 403 error for all browsers.

I tested it by initiating the same call in firebug console, it works (status: 200)

What is the problem can be deduced?

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: "cart_ajax_get_product.php", 
    data: {id: 355, qty: 1}, 
    success: function(data) { }); }, 
    error: function(err) { } 
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we get some of your code to help you out better.

Comment: 403 is a permissions error, which could stem from the AJAX method expecting a post request instead of a get request from your browser. But without code or at least a link to the page that's causing the problem, we can only guess.

Comment: <code>jQuery.ajax({ url: "cart_ajax_get_product.php", data: {id: 355, qty: 1}, success: function(data) { }); }, error: function(err) { } });</code>

Comment: I asked my hosting company,,, and got reply that my website violate some restriction rule detecting for sql injection by mod_security .... it should relate to cookies, raw: "%7B%22cart%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A305%2C%22qty%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D", value: "{"cart":[{"id":305,"qty":1}]}"    could anyone help for this problem ?

Comment: more findings:  cookie causes 403: {"cart":[{"id":411,"qty":"4"}]}, I modified it as {"cart":[{"id":411,"qty":4}]} by Firebug  and refresh the page, 403 disappeared.  I don't know why.

Comment: Finally, i get it work by just modified javascript to parse integer value to avoid string value.

Comment: consider answering your question for the benefit of others

Answer (score 1):

Might be an issue related to apache mod_security.  Try forcing the ajax request to `GET` instead of `POST`:

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
    type:"GET",
    url: "cart_ajax_get_product.php", 
    data: {id: 355, qty: 1}, 
    success: function(data) { }); }, 
    error: function(err) { } 
});
```

Or if that doesn't help...

You could try setting these options on the server's .htaccess, or configuring them elsewhere:

```
SecFilterScanPOST Off
SecFilterEngine Off
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
url: "cart_ajax_get_product.php", 
data: {id: 355, qty: 1}, 
success: function(data) {

}
error: function(err) { } 
});
```